# app fc on query of sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Sorry for the noop question but I just cant seam to get it to work.  I created my database table with this command:

```
    newLeaseTable = "create table '" + leaseName + "' (_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + " Date TEXT, StockTank1Ft NUMERIC, StockTank1Inch NUMERIC,"
            + " StockTank2Ft NUMERIC, StockTank2Inch NUMERIC, StockTank3Ft NUMERIC,"
            + " StockTank3Inch NUMERIC, StockTank4Ft NUMERIC, StockTank4Inch NUMERIC,"
            + " Change1 NUMBER, Change2 NUMBER, Change3 NUMBER, Change4 NUMBER, User TEXT);";
    myDataBase.execSQL(newLeaseTable);
```

when I query the database with either a rawquery or query statement the app crashes and the log points to my query statement.  I want to look in table "LeaseNames" for a string in the column "colLeaseNames" that matches the variable string "enterLogLN" (which is from an editText) and then return the integer from the "colWaterWells" column of the same row. Could anyone help with this,

Thanks

in this case the variable "enterLogLN" is "about"
he

```
re is my rawquery and logcat:
    String col[] = {"colLeaseNames", "colWaterWells"};
    String test = "Select * from LeaseNames Where " + col + " ='" + enterLogLN + "'";
    return Cursor cRWLeaseInfo = myDataBase.rawQuery(test, null);
logcat:
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "[Ljava.lang.String;@405397e0 ='about'": , while compiling: Select * from LeaseNames Where [Ljava.lang.String;@405397e0 ='about'
```

Comment: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "[Ljava.lang.String;@405397e0 ='about'": , while compiling: Select * from LeaseNames Where [Ljava.lang.String;@405397e0 ='about'

Comment: How about editing your question with the full stack trace of the crash. Also, your question shows the INSERT query, but what about the SELECT query that is causing the crash?

Comment: +1 to azgofler, Problem must be in table/column names which we can't know untill you post table_creation query..

Comment: String test = "Select * from LeaseNames Where " + col + " ='" + enterLogLN + "'"; what is col ?

Comment: sorry I copy and pasted the insert command and not the create table code, question is updated now.  the variable col is declared in the line above what you quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
String test = "Select * from LeaseNames Where " + col + " ='" + enterLogLN + "'";
```

Change to:

```
String test = "Select * from LeaseNames Where " + col[0] + " ='" + enterLogLN + "'";
```

A better query:

```
Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query("LeaseNames", null, "colLeaseNames=?", new String[] { enterLogLN } , null, null, null);
```

Comment: that did it, I knew it had to be something simple

Answer (score 0):

We do database insertion operation in Android  in this way.

```
     SqliteDataBase SDB = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();// values to insert into DB Table
    values.put(COLUMNE_NAME1, "data1");
    values.put(COLUMND_NAME2, "data2");
    values.put(COLUMND_NAME3, "data3");
    long id = SDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values); // inserting into table_name will return row id
    Log.d(TAG, "Event Inserted : " + id); 
    SDB.close();
```

Why don't you try this way.